# Disable autocomplete on textfield in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, autocomplete

Does anyone know how you can turn off autocompletion on a textfield in Django?

For example, a form that I generate from my model has an input field for a credit card number. It is bad practice to leave autocompletion on. When making the form by hand, I'd add a autocomplete="off" statement, but how do you do it in Django and still retain the form validation?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your form, specify the widget you want to use for the field, and add an `attrs` dictionary on that widget. For example (straight from the [django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)):

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special'}))
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField(
               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'40'}))
```

Just add `'autocomplete': 'off'` to the attrs dict.

Comment: Thanks! I found this 1 minute before your answer...isn't that how it always goes?!

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Chrome. It still autocompletes username and password fields, even when autocomplete=off.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: Since `attrs` is a dictionary it should be `'autocomplete': 'off'`.

Comment: Just for the sake of finding easily the answer : the link shared by @codescribblr proposes to replace "off" by "new-password". Worked for me (while all other solutions didn't)

Comment: Update - as of now 'autocomplete':'off' or 'false' is not working.

Answer (score 37):

Add the autocomplete="off" to the form tag, so you don't have to change the django.form instance.

`<form action="." method="post" autocomplete="off">
{{ form }}
</form>`

Comment: and how i apply this through ModelAdmin ?

Comment: it does  not work anymore

Comment: This work for me. I test on chrom, mozila. thanks

Comment: @MarkAnthonyLibres just add the code to your `html` file templates want have the form.

Answer (score 13):

If you are defining your own forms, you can add attributes to your fields in the form.

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'autocomplete':'off'
    }))
```

If you are using modelforms, you won't have the luxury of defining field attributes in the form. However, you can use `__init__` to add required attributes.

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({
            'autocomplete': 'off'
        })
```

You can also add attributes from `Meta`

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me adding extra attribute in templates also worked:

```
<form method="POST", autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}`
```

Comment: and how i apply this in auto generated form using ModelAdmin ?

Comment: @MarkAnthonyLibres  just add to html file templates.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using django inbuilt forms for example login forms, or usercreationform as opposed to your own custom model forms, then you will have to remove autocomplete in javascript

```
const username = document.getElementById("id_username");
username.autocomplete = "off"
```